# Finding process information from process id in android

Tags: android, process, pid

i am making an application in android. In that application i want to find process related information from process id. Is this possible? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html). There are methods there to get information about processes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what information you're looking to find out from the pid, but `ActivityManager`'s `RunningAppProcessInfo` class may help.  Try something like this:

```
TextView textProcessInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.processinfo);
int pid = Process.myPid();
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : am.getRunningAppProcesses()){
            if(processInfo.pid == pid){
                textProcessInfo.setText("processName="+processInfo.processName+"\n");
            }

        }
```

This creates a reference to an instance of `ActivityManager`, and then searches through the list of running pids for the app's own. Then it places that pid's `processName` in a `TextView`.  There are other fields and methods of course; `processName` is just an example.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html.